# Cannot find class in classpath: com.orange.testcases.LoginPageTest,

Tags: selenium

I'm getting the below error 
Tried project refresh, Maven Build, Maven Clean but none of these work - Any suggestions will be appreciated

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.orange.testcases.LoginPageTest`
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your TestNG cannot find class with this name, by path you provided in your testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <suite name="Suite">
   <test name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="com.orange.testcases.LoginPageTest"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Probably u changed class name or moved to other directory. Double check this path its gonna fix your problem.